# Error for Sound file : Not a valid AMP page

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

There are problem in some page in my site, When you test this page:

https://search.google.com/search-console/amp?utm_source=wmx&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=wmx-agg&id=QJ9owsgYpzMn_4iKKSbvuw

we show Not a valid AMP page
Invalid AMP pages will not have AMP-specific features in Google search results.

in this code:

```
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/saudigamer/saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3?_=1"/></amp-audio></div><p class="powerpress_links powerpress_links_mp3">Podcast: <a href="http://traffic.libsyn.com/saudigamer/saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3" class="powerpress_link_pinw" target="_blank" title="Play in new window" rel="nofollow">Play in new window</a> | <a href="http://traffic.libsyn.com/saudigamer/saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3" class="powerpress_link_d" title="Download" rel="nofollow" download="saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3">Download</a></p>
```

Are AMP support sound file ?!

Answer (score 0):

need to include amp-audio javascript extension

```
<script async custom-element="amp-audio" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-audio-0.1.js"></script>
```

below line should work replacing "http" with "https" and by adding the missing open amp-audio tag at the beginning

```
<amp-audio><source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://traffic.libsyn.com/saudigamer/saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3?_=1"/></amp-audio></div><p class="powerpress_links powerpress_links_mp3">Podcast: <a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/saudigamer/saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3" class="powerpress_link_pinw" target="_blank" title="Play in new window" rel="nofollow">Play in new window</a> | <a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/saudigamer/saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3" class="powerpress_link_d" title="Download" rel="nofollow" download="saudigamer_e212_010913.mp3">Download</a></p>
```